# S3 inherited permissions or another solution for cross-account multiple access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I'm trying to set up a little bit more complicated S3 Access Setup in Amazon Web Services S3.

The environment consists of the following:

`Account A
- User/Role X
Account B
- User/Role Y
Account C
- User/Role Z
- Bucket 1`

User/Role X, Y and Z have the "AdminstratorAccess"-Policy attached:

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}`

On Bucket 1 is the following Bucket-Policy mapped:

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddPermGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [ "arn:aws:iam::ACCCOUNT-B:user/someuser" ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddPermGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [ "arn:aws:iam::ACCCOUNT-A:user/someuser" ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddPermList",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [ "arn:aws:iam::ACCCOUNT-A:user/someuser" ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3bucket"
        }
    ]
}`

Definition:

`Account C is Owner of Bucket 1`

My Tests:

`uploading a file with user/role Z of Account C in Bucket 1 --> accessible for everyone granted in bucket policy --> User X and Z can access the file
uploading a file with user/role Y of Account B to Bucket 1 --> accessible only for user/role Y regardles of bucket policy content
uploading a file with user/role Y of Account B to Bucket 1 with "bucket-owner-full-control" (as defined in http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#canned-acl) --> accessible only for user/role Y and Z - but X gets: fatal error: An error occured (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden. A list bucket works for all Users including X.`

I'd like to reach, that a file uploaded by user/role Y of Account B to Bucket 1 has the same behaviour as user/role Z of Account C (the owner of the bucket) would upload the file. Clearly: I need access defined by the Policy, not by the File itself. Is it possible to enable "inheritance"?

Cheers,
Matthias